# How to create a multi dimensional NumPy Array for multi classes in deep learning?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, numpy-ndarray, image-classification

I am following a siamese network [example](https://github.com/shubham0204/Face_Recognition_with_TF/blob/master/DataProcessor.py) for face recognitions and it uses only **two classes**, with **3 images per each class** (i.e. 6 total images). How can i modify following code to read and label into **6 image classes**, with **10 images per each class** (i.e. 60 total images)?

```
sub_dir_list = os.listdir( dir_path )
images = list()
labels = list()
for i in range( len( sub_dir_list ) ):
    label = i
    image_names = os.listdir( os.path.join(dir_path , sub_dir_list[i]) )
    for image_path in image_names:
        path = os.path.join(dir_path , sub_dir_list[i] , image_path )
        try :
            image = Image.open(path)
            resize_image = image.resize((dimen, dimen))
            array_ = list()
            for x in range(dimen):
                sub_array = list()
                for y in range(dimen):
                    sub_array.append(resize_image.load()[x, y])
                array_.append(sub_array)
            image_data = np.array(array_)
            image = np.array(np.reshape(image_data, (dimen, dimen, 3))) / 255
            images.append(image)
            labels.append(label)
        except:
            print( 'WARNING : File {} could not be processed.'.format( path ) )

images = np.array( images )

samples_1 = list()
samples_2 = list()
labels = list()
for i in range( 6 ) :
    for j in range( 6 ) :
        samples_1.append( images[i] )
        samples_2.append( images[j] )
        if i < 3 :
            if j < 3 :
                labels.append( 1 )
            else:
                labels.append( 0 )
        else :
            if j > 2 :
                labels.append( 1 )
            else:
                labels.append( 0 )

X1 = np.array( samples_1  )
X2 = np.array( samples_2 )
Y = np.array( labels )
```

Comment: You need to add more folders into `sub_dir_list` (one for each label) and have 10 images in each folder.

Comment: @Shaido-Reinstate Monica yes i have added 6 separate folders, each consist of 10 images of that class, to  the sub_dir_list as your comment. What i need to know is how should i change above code in accordance with my change that contains 6 classes instead of 2 classes in above code.